# Change text alignement upon flex break

Tags: css, flexbox, text-alignment

I'm writing a form that's supposed to be responsive, that is, when the browser window is small the left label "jumps" on top (see example below by removing the `text-align` property and resizing the browser).

Right now, it works well when the label text is left aligned.
For usuabilities issue, I'd like the label to be right aligned (I don't want them too far from the input box) but as soon as the flex has wrapped, I don't want them to be right aligned anymore.

Example code: https://jsfiddle.net/xhtfqbzL/

```css
.cont {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
span
{
  flex: 1 0 20vw;
  text-align: right;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
}
input
{
  flex: 1 1 20rem;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class='cont'>
<span>Label</span>
<input type="text" placeholder="content">
</div>
```

So how to achieve this effect ?

Comment: media query maybe?

Comment: I'd like to avoid using media query since I've no idea at what size to break (and it changes), I'd like to have the size set dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Right now, my best attempt is this:

```css
   html, body { padding: 0; margin: 0 }
   .cont
{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.cont span, .cont input
{
    display: inline-block;
}

.cont span
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-align: right;
    background: blue;
    flex: 1 0 20rem;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 40rem) { 
    .cont span { text-align: left; }
}

.cont input
{
    background: green;
    flex: 1 1 50vw;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class='cont'>
    <span>Some Label</span>
    <input type="text" value="Text here">
</div>
```

I did not want to have media queries because there's always the pain to find the breaking point (and this can evolve based on the design changes or device evolutions). Here, I've *still* used media queries but the `40rem` magic value is computed, not selected by hand.
Typically, one of the form's row item has a fixed size, the other being relative to the viewport size. In this example, the fixed size is `20rem`.

Since they are flex items, they'll wrap when they can't fit anymore on this row, that is when their width will reach their `flex-basis` property.

Thus, the width of the row is `span_width[20rem] + input_width[50% * w] = 100% * w`
I'm deducing that they will wrap when `100% w = 50% w + 20rem => 50%w = 20rem => w = 40rem`

So they'll wrap when the viewport's width becomes lower than `40rem`.

The main issue with this is that you must know the exact margin & padding size around such items and this is a real pain to maintain.

## Another solution which is not using media queries:

```css
   html, body { padding: 0; margin: 0 }
#test
{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
}
#test p
{
    flex: 0 1 20rem;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#test p s
{
    width: calc((48vw - 100%) * 5000);
    min-width: 1%;
    max-width: 16rem;
    
    display: inline-block;
    background: salmon;
    height: 1rem;
}
#test p span
{
    background: red;
    padding-right: 0.5rem;
}
#test b
{
    flex: 1 0 50vw;
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
    <p>
        <s></s>
        <span>First</span>
    </p>
    <b>Second</b>
</div>
```

This works this way:

1. The label is split in 2 inline elements, a spacer and the label itself.
2. The spacer is using the Fab Four trick, that is, the `width` property is calculated to oscillate between `+infinite` and `-infinite` in order to be constrained by either `min-width` and `max-width`.
3. The breakpoint is set by the 2nd item in the flex's row (in the example, `window_width:100vw - input_width:50vw`): when the size left for the label is smaller than the minimum width of the row, its `max-width` property is used and this adds a "space" push the label element to the right. When the flex row wraps, the size left is now very large and above the breakpoint, and thus the `min-width` is selected (in my example, I've used `1%` but it can be `0%`, that is, almost no "margin" on the left of the label).

The caveat of this technic is that you must add a element (could probably be done with a `::before` pseudo element here) and you must set a `max-width` less than the `parent width - label width`.
That point makes this solution is a pain to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a *hack* to be used with caution *(or not used at all ...)*

```css
.cont {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cont:before {
  content: "";
  flex: 1 0 20vw;
  height: 1.2em;
}

span {
  flex: 1 1 20rem;
  position: relative;
}

span:before,
span:after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
}

span:before {
  left: 0;
  bottom: 100%;
}

span:after {
  top: 0;
  right: 100%;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='cont'>
  <span data-text="Label">
  <input type="text" placeholder="content">
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not very fond of the dual label made from an attribute and the overflow rule here since it would break accessibility. Thank for the method however, it's very clever.